I am facing issues connecting via MTLS to AMQ using Quarkus-Camel in version 3.9.1, whereas it was functional for me in 3.8.3
created myClassFactory that extended ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory and set in constructor MTLS info (brokerURL,username,password,trustStore,trustStorePassword,trustStoreType,keyStore,keyStorePassowrd)
in application.properties set to the camel jms component the factory myClassFactory:
camel.component.jms.connectionFactory = #class:com.example.amq.myClassFactory


when started using  <quarkus.platform.version>3.9.1</quarkus.platform.version>
getting error:
2024-04-02 12:28:00,940 ERROR [org.apa.cam.qua.mai.CamelMainRuntime] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route activemq-routing because of Failed to instantiate PooledConnectionFactory: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.setUp(RouteService.java:131)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doInitRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:88)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2387)
        at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.FastCamelContext.doInit(FastCamelContext.java:194)
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:78)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2021)
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:105)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2040)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:212)
        at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.doStart(CamelMain.java:91)
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113)
        at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.startEngine(CamelMain.java:137)
        at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMainRuntime.start(CamelMainRuntime.java:49)
        at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelBootstrapRecorder.start(CamelBootstrapRecorder.java:45)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot173480958.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot173480958.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:111)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)

when build integration routing using activemq endpoint with MTLS factory settings it was functional in  <quarkus.platform.version>3.8.3</quarkus.platform.version>, could connect to the AMQ
